# Group and update multiple records sql based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am stuck trying to figure out a way to execute an update over an entire table on field 'Factor'.

'Factor' is determined by the number of repeated records with the same 'location' and 'date'.

There is a factor calculation table:

```
Location - Count - Factor
   X     -   1    -   1.0
   X     -   2    -   0.8
   X     -   3+    -  0.5
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A
SET Factor = CASE WHEN B.N = 1 THEN 1.0
             WHEN B.N = 2 THEN 0.8
             WHEN B.N >= 3 THEN 0.5 END
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Location, COUNT(*) N
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Location) B
    ON A.Location = B.Location
```

Another way:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Location) N
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Factor = CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN 1.0
             WHEN N = 2 THEN 0.8
             WHEN N >= 3 THEN 0.5 END
```

Comment: I think the request was to partition (or group) by Location and Date.  Also, perhaps he wants the factor to be table-driven rather than hardcoding it with a CASE statement.  In that case, the calculation table should probably have a MinCount and MaxCount column (no "3+") so that the counts can be used in a JOIN condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use derived table with OVER clause

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Factor = x.NewFactor
FROM (   
      SELECT Factor,
             CASE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Location, [date]) 
               WHEN 1 THEN 1.0 
               WHEN 2 THEN 0.8 
               ELSE 0.5 END AS NewFactor               
      FROM dbo.test30
      ) x
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76687/1/1)